# How to submit a form in PHP without a refresh or using jQuery or AJAX?

Tags: php

I've Googled around for this one a bit and can't seem to find a simple answer.

I have a form which I submit over to a PHP script for some validation. What I'm trying to do is submit but without the refresh and without using jQuery or AJAX.

Is there a way to do it in pure HTML or PHP?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? It's one or the other, I think.

Comment: you can use javascript

Comment: no way to do it in "pure" HTML or PHP, you have to use client script in 'background' (js,ajax,jquery -> google for examples) that will push the values to php for you.

Comment: Javascript would be Ajax, Biswajeet.

Comment: @Biswajeet — What could you do with JavaScript to achieve this other than Ajax? Didn't you notice the question asking for a solution in "pure HTML or PHP"?

Comment: yes my friends no other option is there except javascript .    we can validate the input field  javascript for which we don't want any js library file like jquery,or no need to refresh as php, no need of Ajax xmlRequest for that i suggest javascript

Comment: If the only purpose of that (initial) submit is the validation, I suggest to validate that form in javascript and only then, when the validation is finish (including modifications by the user) send the form.

Answer (score 2):

Set the form's `target` attribute to point an an `iframe` element.

Comment: The old fashion way got lost in the web 2.0 process :)